# How do I run a django TestCase manually / against other database?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have some methods written into a `django.test.TestCase` object that I'd like to run from the 
`manage.py shell` on my real database.  But when I try to instantiate the TestCase object to run the test method, I get this error:

```
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'track.tests.MentionTests'>: runTest
```

Is there a way to instantiate the `TestCase` objects?  Or is there a way to run a test method against a non-test database?

Answer (score 16):

Here's a method that I found recently.  I haven't found anything better yet.

```
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
from unittest import TestResult
from my_app.tests import TheTestWeWantToRun

setup_test_environment()
t = TheTestWeWantToRun('test_function_we_want_to_run')
r = TestResult()
t.run(r)
r.testsRun # prints the number of tests that were run (should be 1)
r.errors + r.failures # prints a list of the errors and failures
```

According to the docs, we should call [`setup_test_environment()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#running-tests-outside-the-test-runner) when manually running tests.  `django.test` uses `unittest` for testing so we can use a [`TestResult`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult) from `unittest` to capture results when running the test.

In Django 1.2, [`DjangoTestRunner`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#defining-a-test-runner) could be used for more structured testing.  I haven't tried this yet though.

Comment: When I do this my TestCase cannot access self.client. Also is it possible to run all test functions inside of TestCase without fiddling with getattr etc?

Comment: what I really want is to run the test case under pdb.

Answer (score 3):

The "runTest" problem does usually come up as people do overlook the fact that the unittest.TestCase does have a default argument in its constructor. Have a look at lib/python/unittest/case.py

```
class TestCase:
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
```

Notice that the baseclass "TestCase" does not provide a default implementation of "def runTest" but it does nethertheless try to invoke it. That's where the error comes from. The actual confusion comes from the fact that using "unittest.main()" does not need a runTest method but it will still call all "def test*" functions. This works ... but not because of a default behaviour of TestCase but the inspection code from unittest.main - this is doing something like the following:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_001(self):
        print "ok"

if __name__ == "__main__":
     suite = unittest.TestSuite()
     for method in dir(MyTest):
         if method.startswith("test"):
             suite.addTest(MyTest(method))
     unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Answering the original question "I have some methods written into a django.test.TestCase": you need to add each method individually onto a testsuite by using your testclass and providing the target method name as the first argument upon object creation.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django testing docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/):

> Running tests
>
> Once you've written tests, run them
>   using the test subcommand of your
>   project's manage.py utility:
>
> $ ./manage.py test
>
> By default, this will run every test
>   in every application in
>   INSTALLED_APPS. If you only want to
>   run tests for a particular
>   application, add the application name
>   to the command line. For example, if
>   your INSTALLED_APPS contains
>   'myproject.polls' and
>   'myproject.animals', you can run the
>   myproject.animals unit tests alone
>   with this command:
>
> $ ./manage.py test animals
>
> Note that we used animals, not
>   myproject.animals. New in Django 1.0:
>   You can now choose which test to run.
>
> You can be even more specific by
>   naming an individual test case. To run
>   a single test case in an application
>   (for example, the AnimalTestCase
>   described in the "Writing unit tests"
>   section), add the name of the test
>   case to the label on the command line:
>
> $ ./manage.py test
>   animals.AnimalTestCase
>
> And it gets even more granular than
>   that! To run a single test method
>   inside a test case, add the name of
>   the test method to the label:
>
> $ ./manage.py test
>   animals.AnimalTestCase.testFluffyAnimals

The last example should be applicable in your case.

If this is what you are doing, you'll need to post a more detailed description of the code employed in your test case.

Comment: Sure, but that creates a new test database to run against.  How do I run it against the main (non-test) database?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this, and worked out the following solution:

In your *myapp/tests.py*, set things up like this:

```
# get the straight-up Python unittest without the Django machinery                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# NOTE: this is unittest2, a backport of unit testing features from Python 2.7                                                                                                                                                                                                
# (running 2.6 at the time of writing)                                                                                                                                                                                            
from django.utils import unittest
# get the Django wraps                                                                                                                                                                         
from django.test import TestCase as DjangoTestCase

# [..]
# your normal Django unit tests, inheriting from DjangoTestCase
# [..]

class MyTest( unittest.TestCase ):
    def runTest( self ): # NOTE: required name
        self.failUnless( True is True )

def runNonDjangoTests():
    return MyTest() # or unittest.TestSuite( [ MyTest(), .. ] )
```

You run this test with

```
~$ unit2 myapp.tests.runNonDjangoTests
```

For more info, see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2

This also lets you run unit tests against the main database, with all the potentially destructive side effects. Note that *unit2* is pretty dangerous in this context, if you call
*unit2 myapp.tests* it will run all your normal Django tests without staging them to a test database.