# Execute Django Testcase Suite Manually

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

**Scenario:**

Suppose I have some python scripts that do maintenance on the DB, if I use unittest to run tests on those scripts then they will interact with the DB and clobber it. So I'm trying to find a way to use the native Django test suite which simulates the DB without clobbering the real one. From the docs it looks like you can run test scripts using `manage.py tests /path/to/someTests.py` but only on `Django > v1.6` (I'm on `Django-Nonrel v1.5.5`).

I found [How do I run a django TestCase manually / against other database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374658/how-do-i-run-a-django-testcase-manually-against-other-database), which talks about running individual test cases and it seems dated--it mentions `Django v1.2`. However, I'd like to manually kick off the ***entire suite*** of tests I've defined. Assume for now that I can't kick off the suite using `manage.py test myApp` (because that's not what I'm doing). I tried kicking off the tests using `unittest.main()`. This works with one drawback... it completely clobbers the database. *Thank goodness for backups.*

## someTest.py

```
import unittest
import myModule
from django.test import TestCase

class venvTest(TestCase): # some test
    def test_outside_venv(self):
        self.failUnlessRaises(EnvironmentError, myModule.main)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main() # this fires off all tests, with nasty side effect of
                    # totally clobbering the DB
```

**How can I run `python someTest.py` and get it to fire off all the testcases using the Django test runner?**

I can't even get this to work:

```
>>> venvTest.run()
```

## Update

Since it's been mentioned in the comments, I asked a similar but different question here: [django testing external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681190/django-testing-external-script). That question concerns using `manage.py test /someTestScript.py`. This question concerns firing off test cases or a test suite separately from `manage.py`.

Comment: Are you trying to run specific tests? ``./manage.py test yourapp.tests.venvTest`` ? Supposing ``someTest.py`` should be renamed to ``tests.py``

Comment: No, I'm trying to run a battery of tests external to an application.

Comment: Then isn't this a duplicate? You asked this a little bit earlier on a separate thread

Comment: I think it's a slightly different question (which is why I separated them into two distinct questions). That one concerns executing the script using `manage.py test /someScript.py`. This concerns firing off the tests manually, from the script itself... I.e., totally external to `manage.py test`. Surely, there must be some way to manually fire off testcases?

Comment: why not executing ``./manage.py`` command from ``someTest.py``? ``from subprocess import call
call(...)``

Comment: Because it doesn't work in `Django < v1.6`, according to `Django v1.7` docs and my own experience trying that. Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67817/discussion-between-mihai-zamfir-and-techmedicnyc).